error makes the SDL2 visual studio 2022 project cannot run because error message: LNK1104 cannot open file 'SDL2.lib'
The error that cannot open file 'SDL2.lib' why isn't working bruuuh ???
I try to run the freaking SDL2 visual studio project but it wont wooorrk >:(
IM RAGING RIGHT NOW AND SMASH MY KEYBOARD SO BADLY >:(
this is the case!!! :
Part 1
Part 2
ok if you helping me I say thanks dude :)
I want my project is running so good

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
